# ParameterOverrides property is not valid cloudformation while creating pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline

I'm creating a pipeline with AWS Codepipeline which deploys a lambda function with a cloudformation template, here's my template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  ImageUri:
    Type: String
  LambdaName: 
    Type: String
  RoleName:
    Type: String
  DatabaseName:
    Type: String
  DatabasePassword:
    Type: String
  DatabasePort:
    Type: String
  DatabaseURL:
    Type: String
  DatabaseUsername:
    Type: String

Resources:
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Ref RoleName
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Action:
            - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
              - lambda.amazonaws.com
        Version: 2012-10-17
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess

  LambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Ref LambdaName
      PackageType: Image
      MemorySize: 256
      Timeout: 5
      ImageUri: !Ref ImageUri
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DATABASE_DATABASE: !Ref DatabaseName
          DATABASE_PASSWORD: !Ref DatabasePassword
          DATABASE_PORT: !Ref DatabasePort
          DATABASE_URL: !Ref DatabaseURL
          DATABASE_USERNAME: !Ref DatabaseUsername
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
          - LambdaRole
          - Arn
```

I'm trying to add override parmeters in `codepipeline` deployment stage under `advanced` but when I release changes it tells me that

> "ParameterOverrides property is not valid".

Any help?!

Comment: Could you maybe provide the .yaml which actually contains the CodePipeline resource?

Comment: I'm creating the pipeline in UI not with any yaml file.

Comment: from the documentation `Parameter overrides` [You can specify a JSON object that overrides template parameter values in the template configuration file. All parameter names must be present in the stack template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-action-reference.html). Are you providing all of them plus there is a size limitation of `1 KB`

Comment: Can you provide the text you are putting into the console? Maybe a screenshot? It’s not really popsicle to provide solutions without seeing the whole problem.